# Injecting mock into class inherited by class under test?

Tags: java, mockito

I'm writing a unit test for a class A which extends class B. I'm using Mockito and I want to mock a org.slf4j.logger both classes to use. The problem is when class A calls on a method from class B, the mocked logger is not injected into class B so I get a NPE. Is there a way to successfully test this?

```
public class ClassA extends ClassB {

    @Inject
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClassA.class);

    public void classAMethod { 
        LOGGER.debug("u wot m8");
        this.classBMethod();
}

public class ClassB {

    @Inject
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClassB.class);

    public void classBMethod { 
        LOGGER.debug("u wot m8");
    }

}



public class ClassATest { 

    @InjectMocks 
    private ClassA classA = new ClassA
    @Mock
    private Logger mockLogger;

    @Test
    public void testClassA() {
          classA.classAMethod ();
          verify(mockLogger, (times, 2)).debug(Mockito.anyString());
    }
}
```

Comment: can you also post some of the code from your test?

Comment: do you really mean to keep separate instances of `IWantToMockThis` in both parent and subclass?  Or did you intend for `A` to inherit the `IWantToMockThis` field named `object`, in which case you need not redeclare it in `A`?

Comment: @Kevin Walker: That was the way the classes were originally set up, but I was working on a ticket that changed it to what I provided which broke some unit tests. I don't want to add unnecessary details, but "IWantToMockThis" is actually org.slf4g.logger. Both classes need separate loggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Java EE 6 @Inject it will not work outside the CDI container, this is part of the spec. If this is a unit test you have to provide it by yourself.

Comment: Contexts and Dependency Injection, i.e., an application container to support Java 6+ native dependency injection API, i.e. @Inject (and the rest)

Answer (score 4):

Mockito can't inject static final fields. In fact, nobody can, since by definition, a final field can't be assigned twice. And Mockito doesn't inject static fields anyway. Only instance fields.

See [the documentation](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/index.html?org/mockito/Mockito.html):

> However fields that are static or final will be ignored.

Comment: You can use PowerMock to extend Mockito features: http://code.google.com/p/powermock/